# Protection for shed floor and wood surface

Tags: shed

I built the shed floor slightly larger than the shed. Now there is exposed wood. What would you recommend I can put in between the shed floor and wood to protect the wood?

Sorry new to this forum let me share more details.
I built the base as an 8'x8' Frame of pressure-treated wood.
and I had some leftover stuff so I used 2x6 boards on top of it
since the shed is 7x7 I have about 6" to 8" on sides.

Yes I am thinking about using stain for the exposed wood. keep in mind these 2x6 boards were left outside for about 4 years

[image]

Comment: Photos would help

Comment: How much of the floor is exposed beyond the exterior vertical walls of the shed? 1 cm? 5 cm?  more?

Comment: Without pictures about the only thing we could suggest is the usual.  Paint or stain

Comment: Frame challenge: Cut off the extra floor exposed outside the shed walls. This will allow your wall sheathing to protect the edge of the floor, preventing the floor rotting from the outside in.

Comment: @FreeMan  I would suspect the floor support joists were outside of the shed also, instead of just the floor planks/sheets hanging over.  It sounds like the floor is a base for the shed.

Comment: I just uploaded a picture and more details I hope this helps

Comment: This is a pre-fab shed that you built a wooden base for? TBH, I'm really confused why you would make the floor bigger just because you had some extra lumber laying around. What do you intend to do with this extra space sticking out? That's just... confusing...